# Extending the flyweight pattern: an oxymoron?

Tags: design-patterns, php

I'm developing a [BNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form) parser in PHP, for my own flavor of BNF. To keep the resulting parse tree, consisting of objects, as lightweight as possible, I decided to use the flyweight pattern for literals (terminals):

```
class Literal
{
  private static $cache = array();

  private $string = '';

  // private constructor for flyweight pattern
  private function __construct( $string ) {
    $this->setString( $string );
  }

  // flyweight pattern
  public static function fromString( $string ) {
    if( !isset( self::$cache[ $string ] ) ) {
      self::$cache[ $string ] = new Literal( $string );
    }

    return self::$cache[ $string ];
  }

  public function match( SourceInterface $source ) {
    /* algorithm to match source against $this->string */
  }

  /* ... */
}
```

Literals are denoted as strings between (single or double) quotes, e.g.: `"A"` or `'A'`.

My flavor of BNF, however, will also support encoded representations of single character literals, denoted by a percentage sign and either a decimal or hexadecimal demarcation symbol followed by a value, e.g.: `%d48` or `%x30`.

To implement this I'd, preferably, like to extend the `Literal` class, inheriting some of the `Literal`'s functionality, like its `match` method, because ultimately `EncodedLiteral` represents the `Literal` string, that the input source will be matched against.

So, what I played around with was something like the following, but because the `Literal`'s constructor should be kept `private` for the flyweight pattern, I became confused with what to do inside the `EncodedLiteral`'s constructor.

```
class EncodedLiteral
  extends Literal
{
  private static $cache = array();

  private $encodedString;

  // private constructor for its own flyweight pattern
  private function __construct( $encodedString ) {

    // this won't work, since parent::__construct() is private
    // and it would bypass the flyweight pattern if it was protected
    parent::__construct( $this->decodeEncodedString( $encodedString ) );

    // ... and this doesn't make sense, since it would become composition
    // losing the inherited functionality
    $this->literal = Literal::fromString( $this->decodeEncodedString( $encodedString ) );
  }

  // flyweight pattern
  public static function fromString( $encodedString ) {
    if( !isset( self::$cache[ $encodedString ] ) ) {
      self::$cache[ $encodedString ] = new EncodedLiteral( $encodedString );
    }

    return self::$cache[ $encodedString ];
  }

  private function decodeEncodedString( $encodedString ) {
    /* implementation */
  }

  /* ... */
}
```

So, as you can see, I'm kind of stuck here.

Is there a way to solve this, in an elegant manner, without losing the flyweight advantages? Is this a case of choosing composition over inheritance, perhaps? Should I go with the decorator pattern? I kind of dread having to proxy to the methods I'd otherwise inherit with extending `Literal`, though.

Comment: Can't you just keep the decoding of single character literals out of the `Literal` class, leaving it to the code that calls `fromString`?

Comment: @delnan Sorry if I caused possible confusion, but `decodeEncodedString()` would be a method of `EncodedLiteral`, not `Literal`. But, to address your *actual* point: I'm afraid not — I want to be able to reconstruct (print) the BNF grammar from the parse tree with `__toString()` methods. Therefor I need `EncodedLiteral` in the parse tree as well, to reconstruct the encoding symbols.

Comment: In this case, I would consider having an "encoding" object as a member of each literal that contained methods to convert a literal too or from its original form, and then picking that at construction time. Decorator seems to be overkill for this situation.

Comment: @DecentDabbler Exactly what behavior do you want to share between `Literal` and `EncodedLiteral` ? Static method polymorphism doesn't exist and PHP doesn't have generics as far as I know, so I guess you're out of luck if you want to share flyweight behavior that relies on a static cache.

Comment: @guillaume31 I want to share the `match()` method. Since `EncodedLiteral` ultimately is just a `Literal` under the hood.

Comment: @Jules Thanks for your suggestion, I'm going to consider that option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you only want to share the `match()` method, I would take all the flyweight/cache related behavior out of the Literals into a Factory class. This is static behavior so it couldn't have been inherited anyways.

Something along these lines (pardon my lousy PHP)

```php
public class Literal {

  protected $string = '';

  protected function __construct( $string ) {
    $this->setString( $string );
  }

  protected function getString() {
    return $this->string;
  }

  protected function setString($value) {
    $this->string = $value;
  }

  public function match( SourceInterface $source ) {
    // ...
  }
}

public class EncodedLiteral extends Literal {

  protected function setString($value) {
    parent::setString($this->decodeEncodedString($value)) ;
  }

  private function decodeEncodedString( $encodedString ) {
    // ...
  }
}

public class LiteralFactory {
  private static $cache = array();

  public static function fromString($string) {
    // use private cache here and return a Literal
  }
}

public class EncodedLiteralFactory {
  private static $cache = array();

  public static function fromString($string) {
    // use private cache here and return an EncodedLiteral
  }
}
```

Comment: Ooooh, I think I like this, yes! I'll look into this closer later on, today. But this looks very promising! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you extend a concrete class, it's a code smell. Usually you want all concrete classes to be leaves in the hierarchy.

Move the common code to an abstract base class, then have your two types of literal encoding ( quoted or numeric ) be equal base classes, specialising their textual representations only.

You might also want to move your cache to its own class as you'll find yourself repeating the pattern for all the types of literal your grammar caters for.

Alternatively, change your BNF tokeniser and pass the whole literal to the cache rather than just the part between the quotes, and it can determine from the first character being `"`, `'` or `%` how to decode it, so you don't need two classes.

Comment: `Usually you want all concrete classes to be leaves in the hierarchy.` -- [Really?](https://2000thingswpf.files.wordpress.com/2010/12/classhierarchy-2.png)  Wouldn't that make all of your class hierarchies one-level deep?

Comment: I don't agree with your statements about class hierarchy, but I like your proposals. I'm going to experiment with some or all.

Comment: @RobertHarvey no, you can any number of levels of abstract classes. See the second part of http://stackoverflow.com/a/16725093/1527 for non C++ specific reasons